# How can I access picture in picture related function in angular typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, javascript-objects

When I am trying to use picture in picture related any function I am getting these error. And the error is this function does not exist on type of `HtmlVideoElement`. How can I access these new function for chrome in angular?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I declared an new `interface` which extends the `HTMLVideoElement` Interface. This is a work around but removes errors in VScode intellisense.

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant code required and [not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

The PiP API is not (yet ?) exposed by Typescript generated DOM types (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator). In the meantime, you can just augment the existing DOM types with the PiP API in your own code:

```js
declare global {
  interface HTMLVideoElement {
    requestPictureInPicture: () => Promise<any>;
  }

  interface Document {
    exitPictureInPicture: () => Promise<any>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime you can put a file named `pip.d.ts` in the root of your code with [this](https://gist.github.com/Rendez/6e088e8713f47e87ab04efcc22f365b1) in it.